# Why is python copying lists here?

Tags: python

I have a function that is supposed to represent a cube out of a "3D" array, but with one layer having a square in the middle.  I.E.

```
def cube(n):
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    list3 = []


    for a in range(n+2):
        list3.append(str('c'))
    for b in range(n+2):
        list2.append(list(list3))
    for c in range(n+2):
        list1.append(list(list2))


    for d in range(1,n+1):
        for e in range(1,n+1):
            list1[0][d][e]='h'
    return list1

pprint.pprint(cube(2))

>>>

[[['c', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
['c', 'h', 'h', 'c'],
['c', 'h', 'h', 'c'],
['c', 'c', 'c', 'c']],

[['c', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
['c', 'h', 'h', 'c'],
['c', 'h', 'h', 'c'],
['c', 'c', 'c', 'c']],

[['c', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
['c', 'h', 'h', 'c'],
['c', 'h', 'h', 'c'],
['c', 'c', 'c', 'c']],

[['c', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
['c', 'h', 'h', 'c'],
['c', 'h', 'h', 'c'],
['c', 'c', 'c', 'c']]]
```

but I would like this:

```
>>>

[[['c', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
['c', 'h', 'h', 'c'],
['c', 'h', 'h', 'c'],
['c', 'c', 'c', 'c']],

[['c', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
['c', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
['c', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
['c', 'c', 'c', 'c']],

[['c', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
['c', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
['c', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
['c', 'c', 'c', 'c']],

[['c', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
['c', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
['c', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
['c', 'c', 'c', 'c']]]
```

An h in the first layer only.  Why is python doing this?

Comment: You are explicitly copying the lists....

Comment: `list(list1)` returns a copy.

Comment: More to the point, `list(alist)` creates a _shallow_ copy - the behavior you want requires a "deep" copy.

Comment: I'm confused; you assigned `h` to 4 elements, but it shows up in 16.  Doesn't that mean they *aren't* copies, but the same set of 4 elements referenced 4 different ways?

Comment: Lol nice gotcha if you come from C/C++/Java and think 'c' are chars not pointers to a string object.

Comment: deepcopy worked, thank you Tim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a minimal change to get what you want.  First, add

```
from copy import deepcopy
```

Then replace:

```
list1.append(list(list2))
```

with:

```
list1.append(deepcopy(list2))
```